# Node sendgrid ICAS/ICS invitation

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I am using the npm `sendgrid` [Node SendGrid GitHub](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs)

With this I have created the following module:

```
var path = require('path'),
emailTemplates = require('email-templates'),
async = require("async"),
mailConfig = require('../config/email.json'),
templates = require('../config/emailTemplates.json'),
_ = require('lodash'),
sendgrid = require('sendgrid')(mailConfig.sendGridApiKey),
fs = require("fs");
var mymailer = {};

/**
 * Sends an email to either one or multiple users
 * @param template_id (The id key of the template. Can be found in emailTemplates.json
 * @param to String or Array
 * @param from String
 * @param subject String
 * @param keyReplacer Array of objects for keys to replace in the template
 * @param files Array of file objects
 */
mymailer.sendTemplate = function (template_id, to, from, subject, keyReplacer, section, text, files) {
    var email = new sendgrid.Email(), templateKey = templates[template_id];

    if (templateKey) {
        email.setSmtpapiTos(to);
        email.subject = subject;
        email.from = from;
        email.text = text;
        email.html = 'Gief HTML NU:D';
        email.setFilters({
            "templates": {
                "settings": {
                    "enable": 1,
                    "template_id": templateKey
                }
            }
        });
        email.smtpapi.header.sub = prepareSub(keyReplacer, section);
        email.smtpapi.header.section = prepareSection(section);
        email.files = prepareAttachement(files);
        sendgrid.send(email);
    } else {
        console.log('incorrect key');
    }
};
```

Now for some of my mails I wish to send an invitation that can be accepted in your calendar. However I have no idea how to do this and I can't seem to find any information on the subject.

Has anyone tried sending this using sendgrid? And if so can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to upgrade to the newest version of the [Node.js SendGrid Client library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/), you may find that the v3 /mail/send endpoint makes sending calendar invitations much easier.

Here is an example of adding a content type of "text/calendar": https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.js#L57

Here is some documentation on the new v3 /mail/send endpoint if you would rather use it directly:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/index.html
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html

Comment: The example link is broken